# ajax post multi checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am having problems posting this multi checkbox data with ajax.

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['contacts'] as $user => $id) {?>
<li class="contactList"><span><input type="checkbox" name="contact[]" id="contact" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></span><?php echo $user; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

then the ajax

```
        var contact = $("#contact").val()
    var days = $("#days").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'temp_history.php',
        data: {contact: contact, days: days},
        context: document.body,
```

It is not posting the array of contacts as the form would submit normally but is submitting a single contact.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need you get values with loop. Try this:

```
var contact = new Array();
$("input[@name='contact[]']:checked").each(function() {
  contact.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This can be reduced to a one-liner with `map` if you wish: `contact = $('input[name="contact[]"]:checked').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).toArray();`

Answer (score 2):

ID has to be unique in the document. `$('#contact')` will always return just one element.

Furthermore, `.val()` will always return the value of the first element in the set, even if there were more.

Consider using `.serialize` to pass the data:

```
data: $('#some-form').serialize()
```

... which will give you the data in the format `days=X&contact%5B%5D=1&contact%5B%5D=2`

Answer (score 1):

all your checkboxes have the same id,
use a different strategy to collect the value

serialize the form? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/